# Finding the most common entry in a column - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called MyTable like so

```
A    B
101  Dog
209  Cat
209  Cat
209  Dog
193  Cow
193  Dog
101  Dog
193  Dog
193  Cow
```

And I want to pull out the most common `B` for each `A` so it  would end up being like this (note that there can be ties)

```
    A    B
    101  Dog
    209  Cat
    193  Dog
    193  Cow
```

How could I write sql to do this?

Comment: I don't know what this means.

Comment: SQL server? MySQL? Oracle? DB2? or any..

Comment: FYI, RDBMS stands for Relational DataBase Management System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `HAVING` clause instead of `JOIN`.

```
SELECT A, B
FROM table1 o
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(totalCOunt)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT A, B, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM table1
            GROUP BY A,B
        ) x
        WHERE o.A = x.A 
        GROUP BY x.A
    )
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19df7/18)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filtering join to list the `(A,B)` combination with the highest rowcount:

```
select  src.*
from    (
        select  A
        ,       B
        ,       count(*) cnt
        from    YourTable
        group by
                A
        ,       B
        ) src
join    (
        select  A
        ,       max(cnt) as maxcnt
        from    (
                select  A
                ,       B
                ,       count(*) cnt
                from    YourTable
                group by
                        A
                ,       B
                ) comb
        group by
                A
        ) maxab
on      maxab.A = src.A
        and maxab.maxcnt = src.cnt
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb92f/8/0)

If your database supports windowing functions, you can use `dense_rank()`, like:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  dense_rank() over (
                    partition by A
                    order by cnt desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  A
                ,       B
                ,       count(*) cnt
                from    YourTable
                group by
                        A
                ,       B
                ) t1
        ) t2
where   rn = 1
```

[Window function example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb92f/11/0)  Windowing functions are available on recent versions of SQL Server, Oracle and PostgeSQL.

Comment: and +1 for making me know SQLFiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select g3.A,g3.B
from
(
    select A,Max(C) MC
    from
    (
        select A,B,count(*) C
        from (<your entire select query>) tbl
        group by A,B
    ) g1
    group by A
) g2
join
(
    select A,B,count(*) C
    from (<your entire select query>) tbl
    group by A,B
) g3 on g2.A=G3.A and g3.C=g2.MaxC
```

Comment: could you modify this to handle the fact that "tbl" is actually a query within itself that returns these two columns

Comment: @CodeGuy - please see edit. You just put your entire query into the brackets, which will be aliased as "tbl"

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL FIDDLE Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4f97/7)

```
select
    A, B
from
(
  select
      A, B, row_number() over (partition by A order by cnt desc) as RowNum
  from
  (
    select
       T.A, T.B, count(*) over (partition by T.A, T.B) as cnt
    from T
  ) as A
) as B
where RowNum = 1
```